# 504 Gateway timeout for ELB

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer

I have AWS Elastic load balancer which has two healthy instances. If I make a POST request, it gets accepted. But consequent requests throw 504 gateway timeout error. After 5-10 minutes, it accepts 2-4 requests, and then start throwing 504 error. I try to reach is Spring Boot Application hosted on these two instances. There are no application level timeouts. Further time duration between failed and accepted requests vary, so I believe no fixed timeout configuration setting is causing an issue. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Found anything?